# Vectors, Scalar or vector?

Tags: vectors

Given vectors a, b and c, state whether each of the following results in a scalar, a vector, or is not possible. Justify each response.

1. a • (b × c)
2. (a • b) × c
3. (a × b) + (c • d)
4. (a • b) + (c  • d)
5. (a × b) • (c × d)
6. (a • b) × (c • d)

I know that

1. a • (b × c) = scalar
2. (a • b) x c ==> not possible , first is a scalar , 2nd is a vector
3. I dont know
4. I dont know
5. (a × b) • (c × d) ==> scalar
6. (a • b) × (c • d) ==> not possible , both are scalar

But, when it comes to justify my response, what do they mean?

Comment: I think what you explained is "justifying".

Comment: Thanks! but for the first one, what can i say? I don't know the other 2  @kittyL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By saying that the second example is "not possible *because* ($a$ • $b$) is a scalar and $c$ is a vector," you are justifying your answer. The answer is just that it's not possible, the justification is what you wrote afterwards. You've already done it! :)

Comment: And for the other ones? :( the first one I dont know how to justify it

Comment: @Julio You can say this (which is how I assume you thought it through in your head anyway): the cross product of $b$ and $c$ is a vector, and the dot product of $a$ with that vector is a scalar, and so the whole thing is a scalar.

Comment: Nice, and vector dot vector = scalar too?

Comment: @Julio Yes, that's right.

Comment: And in this case, vector plus scalar = ?

Comment: scalar plus scalar? :D

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see the questions you added ... for number three, you are right that it is vector plus scalar, but you can't add a vector and a scalar, so number three is not possible. For number four, a scalar plus a scalar is a scalar.